# Reference rectangles from a broken-up rectilinear Polygon

Tags: java, polygon

Can someone guide me how I can implement the following in java: I need to reference two rectangles after splitting from any rectilinear polygon into two or more pieces.

[Polygon http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/2475/picture1eu.jpg](http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/2475/picture1eu.jpg)

My Algorithm:

```
ArrayList coordinates;
for (int a = 0; a < coordinates.size(); a++)
{
    if (coordinates[a] at point of concave)
    {
        Draw intersecting line North Or South from coordinates[a] depending on 
        which direction remains inside the polygon.
    }
}
```

On this particular diagram both concave edges lie on the same x-axis, however this is not always the case.

I'm guessing I need to use the Shape and Area class? I guess what I'm struggling with the most is what do I use to make the split (regular .drawLine?) and then be able to reference the two rectangles afterwards.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get list of possible rectangles finding all possible combinations of 4 vertexes. Then leave only rectangles (check x and y of neighbour vertexes). Then check whether they intersect each other.

Also they should be inside main Shape (use contains()) method of `Area` created from the `Polygon`.

Does it work?

Comment: Hmm, this sounds promising. I think that would work. I'll try implementing and see how I get on. Thanks